# Can I call -indexPathsForVisibleRows after scrolling UITableView without subclassing?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, delegates, nsnotification

After each scroll (however large or small) of a `UITableView`, I would like to call `-indexPathsForVisibleRows` to run a method on the data that corresponds to visible cells.

Are there any existing notifications or delegate methods I can tap into when a `UITableView` is scrolled? I'd like to avoid subclassing.

**EDIT**

I ended up subscribing to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol and implementing the following delegate method:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the UIScrollViewDelegate methods, they are being called since UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView